# Javascript Jquery slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the code in jquery to let in a slideshow make the first photo appear after clicking next when on the last photo. I know that i need to write only once document ready but i didnt do that yet but i will. here my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="slides.min.jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#links").mouseover(function() {
                    $("#links").animate({
                        'opacity': '1'
                    });
                });
            });
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#links").mouseout(function() {
                    $("#links").animate({
                        'opacity': '0'
                    });
                });
            });
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#rechts").mouseover(function() {
                    $("#rechts").animate({
                        'opacity': '1'
                    });
                });
            });
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#rechts").mouseout(function() {
                    $("#rechts").animate({
                        'opacity': '0'
                    });
                });
            });
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#links").click(function() {
                    $("#slider").animate({
                        left: '+=600px'
                    }, 1000);
                });
            });
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#rechts").click(function() {
                    $("#slider").animate({
                        left: '-=600px'
                    }, 1000)
                });
            });
        </script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>SlideShow</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #Holder {
                height: 400px;
                width: 600px;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-left: auto;
                overflow: hidden;
                position: relative;
            }
            #slider {
                height: 400px;
                width: 2500px;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1;
                float: left;
            }
            #slider img {
                margin:0px;
            }
            #Holder #rechts {
                height: 100px;
                width: 50px;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 10;
                left: 550px;
                top: 0px;
                opacity: 0;
                padding-top: 150px;
                cursor:pointer;
            }
            #Holder #links {
                height: 100px;
                width: 50px;
                padding-top: 150px;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 10;
                left: 0px;
                cursor:pointer;
                opacity:0
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
         <h1><center>DIT IS MIJN OPDRACHT VAN DIETER(SLIDESHOW)</center></h1> 
        <div id="Holder">
            <div id="slider">
                <img src="images/Auto1.JPG" width="600" height="400">
                <img src="images/Auto2.JPG" width="600" height="400">
                <img src="images/Auto3.JPG" width="600" height="400">
                <img src="images/Auto4.JPG" height="400" width="600" />
            </div>
            <div id="rechts">
                <img src="images/PijlRechts.png" width="50" height="100" />
            </div>
            <div id="links">
                <img src="images/PijlLinks.png" width="50" height="100" />
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you're asking people for help, the least you can do is format your code so it's readable.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but if it's minified it saves dozens of bytes! Dozens! @Jozef you say you haven't completed the code; have you tried doing that? Do you know for sure that this doesn't work? Why are you calling `$(document).ready(` so many times?

Comment: I have put in my comment that i know that i shouldnt put the code document ready so many times and that i will change it.  for me it is importent to know only the code to let the first photo appear after clicking next on the last and the same when on first photo clicking previous the last photo to appear. And yeah i should at least format the code but how to do that? I'm new to jquery so take it easy guys on me :-)

Comment: Can someone edit my code to add that function and update my code?

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether an element has any sibling towards one side, which can be done by `$('element').nextAll().length > 0` or `$('element').prevAll().length > 0`veel succes :)
Is this what you are looking for?

http://plnkr.co/edit/T6K4TLz4pBT0PDoL5OzJ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I will try this out somehow.. I was actually expecting someone to resend me the full code i sended but with the code i need to have its function. 
Like i said, i'm new to javascripting.. Bedankt voor uw help :)

Comment: i changed the plunkr to match you problem

Comment: Ok thanks it works but i have now a small problem. The 2 first photos are slided ok but the 3rd photo is slided but i can see a little bit of the 2nd photo also on the left. But thanks for your help, i have learned alot with it.

Comment: Its the margin on every photo i see and i dont know how to remove that.  Slider img margin is 0px and still problem..

Comment: set the margin to -2px

Comment: Thanks, i have solved the problem by adding all the images in html on 1 single line. But your solution should work as well. Thank you for your help. I have learned something out of your help.